# Android Google Map v2 incorrect

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi i Have question about google map v2 in android.

I added GoogleMap using v2 in my app.

when i zoom, it show incorrectly like below picture.

[image: it shows incorrectly...i want it to show more detail map]

Comment: What is incorrect about the picture being shown?

Comment: What exactly is "incorrect"? Are you talking about the tile seam on the left side that's visible due to compression artifacts? Or the fact that it's blurred in general?